Looking for robust tutorial using "Solve-the-Equation" bandwidth for kernel density estimation
I'm doing work currently that is having me produce CDF functions for distributions induced via an arbitrary bounded function $z=p(\vec{x})$, where $p:\mathcal{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathcal{R} \subset \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{D}:=\times_{i=1}^m [a_i,b_i]$ with $-\infty < a_i < b_i < \infty$. More specifically, I am taking random variables $ \vec{X} \sim \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{D})$, and inducing the random variable $Z = p(\vec{X})$, and constructing an approximation, $F_n(z)$ using $n$ samples, to the "true" (possibly/usually unknowable) cumulative distribution function, $F(z)$. I'm constructing this approximation using kernel density estimation using a Gaussian kernel, $K(t) = (2\pi)^{-1/2}\exp(-t^2/2)$, and applying Silverman's Rule-of-Thumb for the value of the bandwidth, $h$. This rule being
$$
h = 0.9 \min\left\{\widehat{\sigma}, \frac{IQR}{1.34} \right\}
$$
(point of order, I've found a lot of different rules being called Silverman's Rule-of-Thumb, so it could be possible that this isn't actually Silverman's Rule-of-Thumb. Correct me in the comments, but this is ultimately irrelevant to my inquiry).
I'd also like to estimate this using the Solve-the-Equation (terrible name branding-wise) bandwidth calculation, but I cannot find any easy-to-understand presentations/sources/references on how to go about doing this. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point to a robust explanation/source of how to do Solve-the-Equation bandwidth for KDE. Especially one that does not gloss over too much detail. This kind of math is not my particular forte. Or, alternatively, present such a robust tutorial here if there is none to be found online. Additionally, please correct anything incorrect in my terminology.
